# Parsing keywords having space in-between the words

Tags: php

I'm fetching data from a website and the below mentioned script works fine when i parse single words like "math,chemistry,science" etc. However, if i try to parse a keyword which contains space in-between like "business math" etc the browser just loads forever it doesn't seem to work. Please guide me..

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$keywords = "business math,chemistry,science";
$keywords = explode(',', $keywords);

foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
    echo '<br><b><font color="red">Keyword: </font><font color="blue">'.$keyword.'</font></b><br>';

    $html = file_get_html('http://www.tutorvista.com/search/'.$keyword);

    $i = 1;
    foreach($html->find('div[style=padding:20px; border-top:thin solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom:none;]') as $element) {
        foreach($element->find('div[class=entry-abstract]') as $div) {
            $title[$i] = $div->plaintext.'<br><br>';
        }
        $i++;
    }
    print_r($title);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.tutorvista.com/search/'.$keyword);
```

That function internally uses file_get_contents(), which doesn't accept spaces and need the URI to be encoded with urlencode().

Try this out:

```
$html = file_get_html( urlencode('http://www.tutorvista.com/search/'.$keyword) );
```

Ref:

http://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/code/208/tree/trunk/simple_html_dom.php#l76
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php